# Set different facebook share data

Tags: jquery, facebook

Hope this makes sense.

I need to use different Facebook data based on the prize chosen.  Not sure how to get this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not so clean, you could use `.data` for keeping the last selected prize.

```
showPrize = function (dial, id) {
  ...
  var prize_zerod = parseInt(id) - 1;
  $(".post-entry-share").data('prize', prize_zerod);
  ...
};

Facebook.bindEntryShare = function () {
  $('.post-entry-share').live('click', function () {
    var prize = PRIZE_DATA[ $(".post-entry-share").data('prize') ];
    FB.ui({
      method      : 'feed',
      name        : prize["share-name"],
      link        : 'http://www.google.com',
      picture     : prize["share-picture"],
      caption     : 'Caption here',
      description : prize["share-text"]
    });
    return false;
  });
};
```

<s>(Note: Subject to change until you clarify what `setLabels` function does.)</s> `setLabels` wasn't relevant after all.

Comment: setlabels just changes the html.